# emscripten stripping functions with -O3

Tags: emscripten

I'm compiling a mildly complex project with emscripten. (At least more complex then simple examples I've found on the web.) First, I build all the individual libraries and applications and archive them (emar). Then, they are linked together into a final executable.

In this project, function pointers are used for callbacks on event handlers. When I link the final executable with -O3, it is stripping the functions used for the callback handlers and the code isn't running properly.

I can fix this by adding EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE to the definition of the function callbacks. But, my project is cross-platform, supporting more than web deployment. So this isn't the best solution.

Is there a good way of preserving all functions just in a single particular library, while still optimizing the rest of the code, so I don't have to modify every individual sub-project/application with platform specific terminology?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Emscripten documentation](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#why-do-functions-in-my-c-c-source-code-vanish-when-i-compile-to-javascript-and-or-i-get-no-functions-to-process), I think LLVM inlined that function and the function is removed.

Another way to make the function alive is adding it to [`EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS`](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html?highlight=exported_functions#calling-compiled-c-functions-from-javascript-using-ccall-cwrap). For example:

```
emcc -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='["_function_1", "_function_2"]'   ...other options...
```

Note that all functions in the list should be prefixed by an underscore.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if the functions are declared as C functions. Since the code is C++ by default, this still means writing custom C code to fix this, although having the function callbacks be C might be the best solution. (Besides somehow getting a bug fix.)